# Parser Error Message: The connection name 'LocalSqlServer' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, database-connection, machine.config

I'm currently setting up my website on a new SQL Server 2008 server, however I'm getting the following error:

```
 Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The connection name 'LocalSqlServer' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty.

Source Error:

Line 158:        <roleManager>
Line 159:            <providers>
Line 160:                <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
Line 161:                <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
Line 162:            </providers>


Source File: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Config\machine.config    Line: 160
```

Why is this? And how can I resolve the issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Well I've never had to do this before
>   on IIS6 and it seems unnecessary. For
>   starters if you are to add a
>   connectionString in the web.config
>   called 'LocalSqlServer' it'll clash
>   with the machine.config? So you have
>   to remove the connection from the
>   machine to add it to the web. This is
>   what I've done as a temporary fix, but
>   I've never seen this setup on IIS6 or
>   IIS7 before.

As Steven said, you do a  in that case, no need to modify the machine config for that.

There surely is another different between both computers for that to have happened. A couple:

- you had a  in the new server, and not in your original server
- you are inheriting a  from another config.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a connection string in the `<connectionStrings>` section of you config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="[your connection here]" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I've never had to do this on IIS6 though? What would I put as the connectionString?

Comment: Well I've never had to do this before on IIS6 and it seems unnecessary. For starters if you are to add a connectionString in the web.config called 'LocalSqlServer' it'll clash with the machine.config? So you have to remove the connection from the machine to add it to the web. This is what I've done as a temporary fix, but I've never seen this setup on IIS6 or IIS7 before..

Comment: Just start your <connectionStrings> with <clear /> and it will start with a fresh list.